# "stick" button behavior in title bar?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, 15.04, desktop-environments, window-manager

I noticed that in Xubuntus *(Xfce)* windows manager settings there's an option to show a **"stick"** button in the title bar of application windows.

Out of curiosity I enabled it *(moved from hidden to show)*. However I am not sure what it does and can't seem to figure it out.

A quick google search gave me no useful results.

**What does it do exactly? How is it useful?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [XFCE Getting Started Guide](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/getting-stated)

> Stick / unstick windows
>
> If you “stick” a window, it will be visible at the same place on all
>   your workspaces. The same repeated action make a window to
>   stick/unstick :
>
> click the stick/unstick button of the title bar open the window menu
>   button from the title bar and choose “Stick” or “Unstick” item use the
>   Alt + F10 keyboard shortcut